# Do I need to install glassfish server to use it as embedded server in application?

Tags: maven-2, ejb-3.1, glassfish-embedded

I am trying to use glassfish as a embedded server in my ejb3.1 project.
below are my maven dependencies..
But when I run my tests it fails to deploy ejb modules.
do I need to set javaee.home or some more variable ?

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-static-shell</artifactId>
            <version>3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

The exception is..

```
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.DATA_CONVERSION:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 214  completed: No
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key iiop.cannot_find_keyalias
```

Comment: thanks. Now I got that i dont need to install app server and embedded ejb container jar is eoungh.
This is my test setup method
@BeforeClass
 protected void setUp() throws Exception {
  facade = (ItemBoundaryFacade) EJBContainer.createEJBContainer().getContext().lookup("java:/boundary-facades/ItemBoundaryFacade");
 }

Answer (score 1):

No. even you dont need glassfish-embedded-static-shell.jar.
If you want to use EJB3.1 only glassfish-embedded-all jar is enough.
If you want to access jpa data sources from ejb3 then you need a domain.xml file in classpath.
You will need to pass property "org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.glassfish.installation.root" while creating a EJB container in client code.(like EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(prop)). value of this property should be a folder name (ex. glassfish).

The folder should have domains\domain1\config\domain.xml file.

You can download and install glassfish v3 and from installation you can copy this file.